# Как получить и открыть в браузере PDF с помощью Jquery.GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, pdf

Делаю так:

```
$.get('/BSS/clients/printBillsJson.action',
            $.extend({date: date}, filterData),
            function(response) {
        var blob=new Blob([response]);
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download="Docs.pdf";
        console.log("blob: ", blob);
        console.log("link: ", link);

        link.click();
    });
```

pзаголовок ответа:

```
Content-Disposition 
attachment;filename="docs.pdf"
Content-Type    
application/pdf
Date    
Wed, 23 Dec 2015 15:01:24 GMT
Server  
Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding   
chunked
```

В хроме предлагает сохранить файл(а хотелось бы, чтобы он открывался), в лисе вообще не работает. Всегда делал такое через ссылки, но в этом случае не удобно, подскажите, пожалуйста куда копать?

Comment: используйте PDF.js библиотеку

Comment: вы можете попробовать убрать заголовок Content-Disposition?

Comment: И можете обьяснить, что не так в варианте со ссылкой?

Comment: В варианте со ссылкой очень не удобно делать это: $.extend({date: date}, filterData)

Comment: Content-Disposition убрал в struts, теперь
Content-Disposition : inline

Comment: PDF.js хоть и большой, но рассмотрю, нельзя ли небольшой пример, как такой ответ обработать?

Comment: С Content-Disposition : inline ничего в поведении не изменилось, хром всё так же пытается сохранить, а лиса никак не реагирует...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал всё же так:

```
var date = $('#billInvoicingDate').val(); // дата в нужном формате строкой
var rows = $('#legalListTableBody .clientRow');
var dateStr = '&date=' + date;
window.open('/BSS/clients/printBillsJson.action?struts.enableJSONValidation=true' + dateStr + '&' + $.param(filterData), 'Документы'); // filterData - объект, $.param корректно его записывает в URL
```

Comment: P.S. через Jquery.GET загружать файлы, увы, не удобно.